# Инкремент в запросе UPDATE MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

В БД имеется 3 столбца. Необходимо сдвинуть записи во 2 столбце на 1 строку.

```
set @x:=1;
update test_sql.a123 set `2` = (select `1` from (select `1`, `ind_date` from test_sql.a123) as `e` where `ind_date` = @x+1) where `ind_date` = (@x:=@x+1);
```

Однако результат работы смущает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По какой-то причине могут игнорироваться итерации 1 и 2?

P.S.: Если изначально задавать set @x:=0, то итогом работы является все строки null, кроме 1й.

Comment: *По какой-то причине могут игнорироваться итерации 1 и 2?* Порядок вычисления выражений - не определён.

Comment: @Akina Посоветуйте пожалуйста какую-нибудь доходчивую статью/литературу, где можно почитать про порядок вычисления выражений в mysql и каким образом его можно определить/задать

Comment: *где можно почитать про порядок вычисления выражений* https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/ и https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/ *каким образом его можно определить/задать* Да в общем никак, наверное, за исключением того, что выражения материализующегося подзапроса считаются раньше выражений основного запроса...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE a123 t1, a123 t2
SET t1.`2` = t2.`2`
WHERE t1.ind_date = t2.ind_date - 1
```